# Update data between databases sqlite - ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, sqlite, database-backups

Here's my case

I've to replace my car company database file with a new one because of some structural changes.

The newer car company table (in the database) has some addition companies compared with the old one.

```
car company
   ( id,
   companyname,
   address,
   phone,
   isUserFavorite,
   ... 
   )
```

I want to backup the user favorite field from old the database, which means I've to `SELECT` and `UPDATE` between 2 databases.

Also, i need to backup the history table, too. (`SELECT` and `INSERT` to newer one).

I think I've to `ATTACH DATABASE`, do my tasks, and then `DETACH DATABASES` when i'm done, right ?

But I don't know how to do that in particular. Do I've to write multiple methods to do these tasks or how can I execute  multiple sqlite's query in one method ?

Thanks

Comment: I don't have the code at hand, but it's all out there if you search for it.

Comment: (It's not clear:  Are you changing the DB schema, or simply adding records.  If adding records, just add them.  Otherwise you can fairly easily copy between old and new DB, but, as I said, I don't have the example in front of me.)